# MASM x86 assembly program compile on linux platform

Tags: masm

I am new for x86 assembly programming ,currently i am compiling and executing  x86 assembly programs on visual studio  with MASM assembler, still it is working, but i don't have clear how to  x86 programs  compile and execute on linux platform, could you any one explain me

advance thanks
By
Ajith

Comment: Have you tried google? http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/

Comment: yes i am  trying google still i didn't valuable point. t

Comment: You want Linux but tagged masm... are you sure about that?

Comment: Besides Micha's link, see this: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/masm.htm

Comment: You're probably better off using NASM and the GNU linker on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wine to run MASM code in Linux using emulator8086.

install wine : `sudo apt-get install wine`

Here is link for emulator: http://www.emu8086.com/